# Dynamic form validation between an HTML and PHP file. Is this possible?

Tags: php, html, css, forms, dynamic

Currently on my site JorgeGoris.com I have a form that is pointing to a php file called form_process.php for validation. My problem is that I never see the validation or success messages I have implemented take place because when I hit submit I am redirected to form_process.php I want this to take place dynamically in the same page. How can I do this? This is my form and php code:

```js
<?php

// define variables and set to empty values
$firstName_error = $email_error = $phone_error = "";
$firstName = $lastName = $email = $phone = $message = $success = "";

//form is submitted with POST method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["firstname"])) {
    $firstName_error = "First name is required";
  } else {
    $firstName = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstName)) {
      $firstName_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }
  
  if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
    $phone_error = "Phone is required";
  } else {
    $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!preg_match("/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i",$phone)) {
      $phone_error = "Invalid phone number"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message = "";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }
  
  if ($firstName_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone_error == '' ){
      $message_body = '';
      unset($_POST['submit']);
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
          $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
      }
      
      $to = 'J_goris@live.com';
      $subject = 'Potential Client/Employer-JorgeGoris';
      if (mail($to, $subject, $message_body)){
          $success = "Message sent, I'll get back to you shortly!";
          $firstName = $email = $phone = $message = '';
          echo "<h1>Got it! I'll get back to you shortly!</h1>";
      }
  }
  
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

?>
```

```html
<form action="form_process.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
    <div class="form-row">
     <div class="col-lg-3 offset-lg-3 col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name *" name="firstname">
      <span class="error"><?php= $firstName_error ?></span>
     </div><!--end col-->
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname">
     </div><!--end col-->
    </div><!--end row-->
    <div class="form-row">
     <div class="col-lg-3 offset-lg-3 col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone">
      <span class="error"><?php= $phone_error ?></span>
     </div><!--end col-->
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email *" name="email">
      <span class="error"><?php= $email_error ?></span>
     </div><!--end col-->
    </div><!--end row-->
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-5 offset-lg-3 col-sm-12">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Tell me a little about your project. Budget details are also appreciated. *" name="message"></textarea>
     </div><!--end col-->
    </div><!--end row-->
    <div class="success"><?php= $success; ?></div>
    <button type="submit" class="button" name="submit">Submit</button>
   </form><!--end form-->
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper method to achieve the desired functionality is to have your form-data sent to the PHP file (or function) which is responsible for loading the form. The PHP code which loads the form should be conditional. For example you can have a check for errors in the submitted post-data and if there's an error some HTML code that displays the error should be outputted in addition to the normal HTML code of the form.

In your case you don't see anything when you hit the submit button because the PHP script to which your form is pointing doesn't output the HTML of the page that contains the form.

Comment: Well my form is an on an HTML page. Is what you mentioned still possible?